# How to sort list of Control type

Tags: c#, list, winforms, sorting, controls

I created list of controls on form like this:

```
List<Control> list = new List<Control>();
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
    {
        list.Add(c);
    }
}
```

All controls in this list are Labels so I need to sort this list of [Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) in ascending order, so I use [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0) method of List class like this:

```
list.Sort();
```

But it says to me `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Failed to compare two elements in the array.' ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.`

Since I want to sort it using [TabIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_TabIndex) value or at least its [Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.name?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Name), it's unclear for me. What should I pass to [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0) method or what should I use instead of this method?

Comment: `var labels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().OrderBy(L => L.TabIndex);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [IEnumerable interface method of OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0) and provide it with a function that specifies what element you are comparing as an alternative to using sort.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var controls = new List<B>() {new B() {Index = 0}, new B() {Index = -1}};
        var sortedControls = controls.OrderBy(x => x.Index).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(controls[0].Index); // -1
        Console.WriteLine(controls[1].Index); // 0
    }
}

public class B
{
    public int Index {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `Comparison` function to `list.Sort`

```cs
var list = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();
list.Sort((a, b) => a.TabIndex.CompareTo(b.TabIndex));
```